# Display remaining time for Thread.Sleep() in Console Application

Tags: c#, .net, timer, console-application

I have a .net Console application which runs infinitely. i have inserted `Thread.Sleep()` for say 5 minutes to pause my application. 
at this point of time i want to display user remaining time (in seconds) for thread to become active and start of application again.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Program program = new Program();
        program.startFeed();
    }
    public void startFeed()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                //My Application which i want to run continously 
                //when thread enters in run mode
            }
            catch (Exception xObj)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString() 
                    + " >> Incoming Message Processing Error. >> " 
                    + xObj.Message);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Waiting For Data......");
            Thread.Sleep(300000);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not use a `System.Threading.Timer` for this?

Comment: @BryanCrosby: Could you remove the question part of your comment?: "Use a `System.Threading.Timer` for this!". :-P

Comment: Could you please give example of that ?

Comment: @SagarDumbre Just do a web search, you'll find lots of examples.

Comment: Is it important that you wait 5 minutes, or would you be willing to process items as soon as they become available?

Comment: Items Which i am processing gets available at a gap of 5 minutes.

Comment: @SagarDumbre And are they staying in sync?  Even if the items are added to the queue in 5 minute intervals what stops them from being added just after you start sleeping?  If that happened then it would be almost 5 minutes before you even started processing those items.  Again, I will ask, is it important that you only process items every 5 minutes, or would you be willing to process items as soon as they come in if it was possible?

Comment: Yes They are in Sync. Could you please help me with my code ? i searched on net but dont have any idea how to relate with my application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current structure of your program does not support what you are trying to achieve.

When you call [Thread.Sleep(int)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d00bd51t.aspx), it suspends the *current* thread for the specified time. By default, your program only runs as a single thread, so suspending that thread stops all your code from being run.

You want to display updates to the user, but you also want your worker process to wait for 5 minutes between runs. This means that you will need to create a separate thread for the worker process, and manage that from the thread your program starts with.

One of the simpler ways to do this is to use [System.Threading.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.aspx), as others have suggested. In your case, you could change your code to something like this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Program program = new Program();
        program.startFeed();
    }

    // This is run on the main thread
    public void startFeed()
    {
        // Start a Timer on a new thread to do work with the ProcessData method
        // Pass null to its 'state' argument, wait 0 milliseconds before
        // running it, and run it once every 300000 milliseconds
        using (new Timer(ProcessData, null, 0, 300000))
        {
            // The Timer will only exist while we are inside the 'using' block;
            // stay here with a loop
            while (true)
            {
                // Write our status message
                Console.WriteLine("Waiting for data at {0}...", DateTime.Now);
                // We don't want this loop running ALL the time; add a small
                // delay so it only updates once every second
                Thread.Sleep(1000); 
            }
        }
    }

    // This is run on the background thread
    private void ProcessData(object state)
    {
        try
        {
            //My Application which i want to run continously 
            //when thread enters in run mode
        }
        catch (Exception xObj)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString()
                + " >> Incoming Message Processing Error. >> "
                + xObj.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Great, so now you have two threads running at the same time, and calling [Thread.Sleep(int)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d00bd51t.aspx) on the one doesn't influence the other. Note that you don't need to call [Thread.Sleep(int)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d00bd51t.aspx) in *ProcessData*, because the [Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.aspx) takes care of that for you.

Finally, you want to show the user exactly when *ProcessData* will run again. You could do this by adding a [DateTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx) field to your *Program* class, say `private DateTime _lastRun;` and at the beginning of *ProcessData*, you could set it to `DateTime.Now`. Then, in the loop in *startFeed*, you could work out how many seconds are left until the next run using something like `_lastRun.AddMinutes(5).Subtract(DateTime.Now).Seconds`.

---

There is a lot more that could be said here. As others have hinted, you are writing polling code instead of event-driven code. Polling is usually slower, less efficient and more complex than the event-driven equivalent. However, it depends on your data source being able to notify your code when it has new data to process; polling might be your only option.

There is also a lot to be said about communication between threads. In and of itself, multi-threading is a very tricky subject and is the cause of many hard-to-find bugs. However, for this example, writing to the Console and setting a shared DateTime field *should* be safe across the two threads.